# How to rename all directories on a terminal

Tags: bash

I have a total of 31 directories. Every directory has a random name.

```
❯ ls -al
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  34 shinokada  staff   1088 Dec 28 17:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  32 shinokada  staff   1024 Dec 28 17:12 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 shinokada  staff  14340 Dec 28 17:16 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x   5 shinokada  staff    160 Dec 28 17:10 05618066
drwxr-xr-x   5 shinokada  staff    160 Dec 28 17:08 0fef2d20
drwxr-xr-x   5 shinokada  staff    160 Dec 28 17:09 11ff096d
drwxr-xr-x   5 shinokada  staff    160 Dec 28 17:09 1651ff1f
drwxr-xr-x   5 shinokada  staff    160 Dec 28 17:09 2123b256
... and more
```

Now I'd like to rename them sample1 sample2 sample3 ...sample31.

How can I do it on a terminal(bash/zsh)?

Is there a quick way to do it rather than `rename` one by one?

Comment: You can't be running Bash and Zsh at the same time. The answers will probably look different for each.

Comment: MacOS does not seem to ship a `rename` tool; there are several incompatible ones, so it's unclear which one you refer to, but if you have the Perl-based one, it can probably do what you are asking in a slick one-liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
num=1; for dir in */ ; do mv "${dir}" "sample$num" ; ((num++)); done
```

I assume you don't want to rename the files, only directories inside your current working directory.

Comment: I just needed to change num=0 to num=1. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you are starting from `sample1`. Thanks for pointing it out (I edited it in the answer).