# How to rename batch file

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

can anyone help me??
I want rename file from

```
Chat WhatsApp dengan A3 - 21.mp4
Mine.mp4
MoviMax_MV1_V016_2.106.001_20150227_2030_fbf.mp4
bedrock_server.mp4
```

to

```
test1.mp4
test2.mp4
test3.mp4
test4.mp4
```

how do i do it??

Comment: Did you try something and have some specific problem? Have you tried `mv "Chat WhatsApp dengan A3 - 21.mp4" test1.mp4`?

Comment: I've tried "mv Chat WhatsApp dengan A3 - 21.mp4 test1.mp4" but actually there are 143 files, and I think it seems like use "mv" command for 143 files is a waste of time, is there a simpler and faster way?? like using the "for" or "while" command

Comment: Yes there is (you should update your question to make it clearer that that is what you are asking about). But SO is not a place to ask for complete code. Do research (e.g. learn bash scripting), make an attempt at the code and then ask a specific question about the code.

Comment: In a directory of 143 files, there will not be a portable way, without using the original names to do so. LOCALE will impact sort order. You can loop and move using `test` and a suffix of increasing numbers, but if you have a requirement to map specific names to `testXXX` you will have to use a `mv` of individual files as shown by @RiccoD

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65474842/how-to-rename-all-directories-on-a-terminal

Comment: You could write some program in C, using [nftw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html), [opendir(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [rename(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) and other [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). See also [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution(7)) and [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html). Or in C++ with [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/)

Comment: Why stop there? You could write it in 8086 assembly!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the "mv" command to rename the files.

> Usage: mv original_file renamed_file

Just take note of files with space, you will need to add back slash (\) before the space so it will be considered as "space".

```
mv Chat\ WhatsApp\ dengan\ A3\ -\ 21.mp4 test1.mp4
mv Mine.mp4 test2.mp4
mv MoviMax_MV1_V016_2.106.001_20150227_2030_fbf.mp4 test3.mp4
mv bedrock_server.mp4 test4.mp4
```

Comment: actually there are 143 files, and I think it seems like using the command "mv" for 143 files is too waste of time, is there a simpler and faster way ??

Comment: Yes, and it's easily discoverable by searching before asking.